# Autowiring a bean based on a property

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, autowired

I have two beans, `beanA` and `beanB`, in my Spring config. Both of these beans implement the same interface. I have a class with an autowired field of the interface type (i.e. it will be populated with an instance of `beanA` or `beanB`).

Initially there was only one bean, so I simply used the `@Autowired` annotation and the field was populated. However, now there's two potential beans that could be autowired. I want to autowire the bean based on the existence of a property in one of my `.properties` resources. Is there any elegant way to do this?

The solution I'm using now is to use the `@Qualifier` annotation on the autowired field to specify `beanA` and then make a check to see if the property exists in code. If it does, I reassign the field to an instance of `beanB`. It's a very clunky way of doing it, so I'm looking for a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the newer feature of bean profiles, you can also [take advantage](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) of [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) which instantiate a bean at the time of access. The idea is to inject the `FactoryBean` with the bean types (e.g. `fqcn.BeanA` or `fqcn.BeanB`). Then factory bean will return the bean factory to instantiate the correct type of the bean that you may need. The configuration of `FactoryBean` then can take advantage of properties coming from a resource bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Bean profiles could be great fit for this - based on the "active" profile let one or the other bean be created.

Somewhat of an older article, but is still a good reference to profiles in Spring 3.1- http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Profile](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) can help

**Configuration Changes**

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>a</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

spring-beans.xml with profiles. Profile value can behave as the
   property value for decision making.

```
<bean id="A" profile="a"/>
<bean id="B" profile="b"/>
```